# What tag to use for elementary polynomial equations?

Tags: discussion, tagging, tag-management, tag-blacklist

Many questions on MSE posted by elementary school (or high-school) pupils are of the form *"find $x$ if $x^{101} = x^{51}$"* (this is a real example that has just got posted). Clearly, this question is neither about *(polynomials)* (even though it involves monomials), neither about *(exponentiation)*. It is about algebraic equations, but most pupils of this mathematical level would never know to use this term, all they know is "equations". The *(algebra-precalculus)* tag is waaay too general. I therefore tried to create the tag *(equations)* but, to my surprise, got the message *"The 'equations' tag is not allowed"*. Really? On MSE? So *(geometry)* and *(analysis)* are fine, but *(equations)* is not?

1) What tag should one use for problems of the type illustrated above?

2) Why is the creation of the *(equations)* tag not allowed? Was it blacklisted? If so, what was the rationale of doing so?

Comment: The point is I think that completely unrelated questions could be seen as questions about "equations." This remains true even if restricted by level. By the way, analysis is basically deprecated as a tag, so it is not fine.

Comment: List of all blacklisted tags [can be found here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/21966/which-are-blacklisted-tags-and-blacklisted-phrases/21967#21967). Usually with some links to discussion which lead to blacklisting.

Comment: @MartinSleziak: Your link points to http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1363/tag-merging-and-synonyms/1936#1936, which answers half of my question. What about the other half?

Comment: This older question seems rather similar to yours: [Tag for a single algebraic equation?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/19402)